# Trying to serve CRA build folder statically in asp.net core 2

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, create-react-app

I created a basic web api, and added a react frontend using `create-react-app`. When in production I want to serve the build folder which gets created by running `npm run build` from `create-react-app` statically. Based on what I found on the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x), I tried the following, but to no avail. I get a 404, and nothing on screen.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsProduction())
            {
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "client/build")),
                    RequestPath = "/static"
                });
            }
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.